# The file path changes after flutter run or update the app

Tags: flutter

I use method `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` in `path_provider` to get the image path.

However, when I `flutter run` or update my app in AppStore, the path got by `getApplicationDocumentDirectory()` will change and I can't get the image by the path stored before.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's easy to solve it.

I used the absolute path of the image so every time I rerun the app, the container id will change, so I cannot get the image with the previous path.

To solve it, you need to use relative path.

Relative Resource: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23957

Comment: Can you give an example please ? it's not working in my case anyway